# How do I get auto layout to reposition a view when it's sibling view changes size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view controller with two views (greenView, redView) and a switch:

[image]

I have a constraint on the redView top space of 50px from greenView. Here are all the constraints on redView:

[image]

I have a switch that when tapped toggles the height of greenView from 50px to 100px.

When I launch the app, the views are laid out as I want, but when the switch is tapped, the greenView frame changes from a height of 50 to 100, the redView doesn't do what I would expect - which is to shift it's y position 50px down to maintain the top space constraint it was assigned. I have an inequality constraint put on the bottom space of redView so there are no conflicts, and I am also calling `[self.redView layoutIfNeeded]`.

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (IBAction)switchTapped {

if (theSwitch.isOn) {

    greenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 100);
    [redView layoutIfNeeded];

} else {

    greenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 50);
    [redView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Why isn't redView's y position being updated?

I have watched WWDC videos, but they seem to mention calling layoutIfNeeded in passing. What am I missing?

Here's what it looks like when launched:

[image]

And here it is when the switch is tapped:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that are causing problems. The first thing is that autolayout is supposed to ignore the object's frame. If you want to change the height of something, you change its height constraint, not the frame height. This is because constraints are applied after your layout and would override any frame changes. In addition, the red view looks like it is constrained to your superview "view" not "greenView". As far as editing the constraints, you can set up an `IBOutlet` and then modify the `constant` property of the `UILayoutConstraint` object.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of pointers:

1. `layoutIfNeeded` assumes that you have previously called `setNeedsLayout`. Use `setNeedsLayout` instead and your app will update the layout as soon as appropriate.
2. Setting a frame generally does not work with autolayout. Set or change a height constraint instead. This is something you should do in code, mros had a good suggestion for this.
3. I find that inequality constraints are usually not the best solution, since they often lead to ambiguous layout. Instead, set an equality constraint, but lower the priority (e.g. to 500). The autolayout system will try to honor the constraint as much as possible, but will prioritize other constraints. (By default, all constraints have 1000 priority.)

Comment: Thanks Maarten, your answer helped too. If I could split my accepted answer I would give you half. :)